# clone(2) with CLONE_FILES leak fcntl locks?

Tags: c, linux, clone, fcntl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define __USE_GNU
#include <sched.h>

void init_lock(struct flock *f)
{
    f->l_type = F_WRLCK;      /* write lock set */
    f->l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    f->l_start = 0;
    f->l_len = 0;
    f->l_pid = getpid();
}

int lock(int fd, struct flock *f)
{
    init_lock(f);
    if(fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, f) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"fcntl() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int unlock(int fd, struct flock *f)
{
f->l_type = F_UNLCK;
if(fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, f) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fcntl() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}
return 0;
}

int file_op(void *arg)
{
char buff[256];
int fd = (int) arg, n;
struct flock my_lock;

printf("Trying to get lock\n");
if(lock(fd, &my_lock) == -1) {    /* lock acquired by a thread */
    return -1;
}

printf("Got lock: %d\n", getpid());  /* I am printing thread id after lock() */
printf("Enter string to write in file : ");
scanf("%s", buff);

if((n=write(fd, &buff, strlen(buff))) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "write() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}

if(unlock(fd, &my_lock) == -1) {
    return -1;
}
printf("Lock Released: %d\n", getpid());
return 0;
}

int main()
{
char *stack;
int fd, i=0, cid, stacksize;

if((fd = open("sample.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0644)) == -1) {
    printf("Error in file opening\n");
    exit(1);
}

stacksize = 3*1024*1024;
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    stack = malloc(stacksize);
    if((cid = clone(&file_op, stack + stacksize, CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_THREAD, (void *) fd)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"clone() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        break;
    }
}
sleep(30);
close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

I want that every clone() will wait for lock.
But Output of this code (something like this):

```
Trying to get lock
Trying to get lock
Trying to get lock
Got lock: Got lock: 10287
Got lock: Got lock: 10287

Enter string to write in file : Trying to get lock
Enter string to wriGot lock: 10287
Got lock: 10287
Got lock: 10287
Enter string to write in file : Trying to get lock
Got lock: 10287
Got lock: Enter string to write in file :
```

But when i am removing CLONE_FILES field set from clone(2), it goes all well. Other clone threads will wait for a lock().

Output of that:

```
Trying to get lock
Got lock: 10311
Trying to get lock
Trying to get lock
Trying to get lock
Trying to get lock
```

Any other alternatives (with CLONE_FILES)? And Why this kind of behavior?

Beginner in this field.

Comment: Please don't use tabs, and make sure your indentation is correct. Especially with a huge code dump like this, few people will have the attention to read through everything if it is tiresomely presented.

Comment: Ohhkk budy. I will take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locking provided by `flock` is per process, not per thread.

From http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock (emphasis mine):

> A call to flock() may block if an incompatible lock is held by ***another process***.
>
> Subsequent flock() calls on an already locked file will convert an existing lock to the new lock mode.
>
> Locks created by flock() are associated with an open file table entry.

Although threads are not explicitly mentioned multiple threads share a file table entry whereas multiple processes do not. Passing `CLONE_FILES` to `clone` causes your 'processes' to share file tables.

A solution might be to call `dup` to make more file descriptors. From the documentation:

> If a process uses open(2) (or similar) to obtain more than one descriptor for the same
>   file, these descriptors are treated independently by flock(). An attempt to lock the file 
>   using one of these file descriptors may be denied by a lock that the calling process has 
>   already placed via another descriptor.

Comment: If i will not use different fds for same file means share/dup a single fd within the process than i think flock will not work too. Am i correct?

Comment: That's correct. However if you do use call dup to get a second fd then flock will work.

Comment: But any proper solution for shared fds (means with CLONE_FILES and without using dup in child threads)?

Comment: No, there's no way of doing that using flock, Linux just doesn't work like that. The solution would be to use a mutex rather than an flock, or if you need to coordinate with other processes also both a mutex and an flock.